# validating parameter dictionaries before insertion in datajoint schema

Tags: python, datajoint

We'd like to enforce parameter checking before people can insert into a schema as shown below, but the code below doesn't work.

Is there a way to implement pre-insertion parameter checking?

```
@schema
class AutomaticCurationParameters(dj.Manual):
    definition = """
    auto_curation_params_name: varchar(200)   # name of this parameter set
    ---
    merge_params: blob   # dictionary of params to merge units
    label_params: blob   # dictionary params to label units
    """
    def insert1(key, **kwargs):
        # validate the labels and then insert
        #TODO: add validation for merge_params
        for metric in key['label_params']:
            if metric not in _metric_name_to_func:
                raise Exception(f'{metric} not in list of available metrics')
            comparison_list = key['label_params'][metric]
            if comparison_list[0] not in _comparison_to_function:
                raise Exception(f'{metric}: {comparison_list[0]} not in list of available comparisons')
            if type(comparison_list[1]) != int and type(comparison_list) != float:
                raise Exception(f'{metric}: {comparison_list[1]} not a number')
            for label in comparison_list[2]:
                if label not in valid_labels:
                  raise Exception(f'{metric}: {comparison_list[2]} not a valid label: {valid_labels}')               
        super().insert1(key, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question that has come up many times for us.

Most likely the issue is either that you are missing the class' `self` reference or that you are missing the case where the `key` is passed in as a keyword argument (we are actually expecting it as a `row` instead).

I'll demonstrate a simple example that hopefully can illustrate how to inject your validation code which you can tweak to perform as you're intending above.

Suppose, we want to track filepaths within a `dj.Manual` table but I'd like to validate that only filepaths with a certain extension are inserted.

As you've already discovered, we can achieve this through overloading like so:

```py
import datajoint as dj

schema = dj.Schema('rguzman_insert_validation')

@schema
class FilePath(dj.Manual):
    definition = '''
    file_id: int
    ---
    file_path: varchar(100)
    '''
    def insert1(self, *args, **kwargs):  # Notice that we need a reference to the class
        key = kwargs['row'] if 'row' in kwargs else args[0]  # Handles as arg or kwarg
        if '.md' not in key['file_path']:
            raise Exception('Sorry, we only support Markdown files...')
        super().insert1(*args, **kwargs)
```

P.S. Though this example is meant to illustrate the concept, there is actually a better way of doing the above if you are using MySQL8. There is a `CHECK` utility available from MySQL that allows simple validation that DataJoint will respect. If those conditions are met, you can simplify it to:

```py
import datajoint as dj

schema = dj.Schema('rguzman_insert_validation')

@schema
class FilePath(dj.Manual):
    definition = '''
    file_id: int
    ---
    file_path: varchar(100) CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(file_path, '^.*\.md$', 'c'))
    '''
```